# Problem with "A PHP Error was encountered : Undefined Index"

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

i have a problem with my code and i don't know how to fix these, i don't know why it said undefined
could you please help me to solve this problems?

```
Message: Undefined index: nik

Filename: controllers/User.php

Line Number: 24
```

these are the code :

```
20    public function edit_profil()
21    {
22        $post = $this->input->post();
23        $data = [
24            'nik' => $post['nik'],
25            'nama' => $post['nama'],
26            'telp' => $post['telp'],
27            'divisi' => $post['divisi'],
28            'email' => $post['email'],
29            'username' => $post['username'],
30        ];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$post` variable doesn't contain, 'nik' key in it.

`Undefined index` means that you array doesn't contain that 'key' in it.

So please dump(`var_dump($post) or print_r($post)`) your `$post` variable first, to see what data comes.

You can see the Controllers documentation [here](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/incoming/controllers.html).

And Request documentation [here](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/incoming/request.html).

Comment: i get it, it helps me to  solve my problem just now , thanks

Comment: Glad to help you :)